# Saving a mobile number to WP contacts wird cordova contacts plugin

Tags: javascript, cordova, save, contacts

I iterate through an array of a few mobile numbers here:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < kondaten.length; i++) {
        if (kondaten[i].typ == "work") {
            phoneNumbers[0] = new ContactField('work', kondaten[i].telefonnummer, null);
        } else if (kondaten[i].typ == "private") {
            phoneNumbers[1] = new ContactField('home', kondaten[i].telefonnummer, null);
        } else if (kondaten[i].typ == "mobile") {
           phoneNumbers[2] = new ContactField('mobile', kondaten[i].telefonnummer, null);
        }
    }
```

Now my problem is: If my app reaches the mobile number, the contact won't be saved. But, if I comment out this line:

`phoneNumbers[2] = new ContactField('mobile', kondaten[i].telefonnummer, null);`

, everything works fine...
Is there an unknown *type* for mobile numbers or is it just impossible to save one?

In the *cordova-plugin-contacts* API, it is referenced that you can only store one number for each type.
[Plugin API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-contacts#windows-phone-7-and-8-quirks)

On this page: [Dzone reference](https://dzone.com/articles/cordova-formerly-phonegap), they use the *mobile* type, and it seems to work properly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything works fine...

The issue was, that sometimes a contact did not have a private number, so the *phoneNumbers[]* had no *[1]* index.

The solution was to push every number, into the array.